# how to convert string multidimensional to Custom Categories with php array and explode?

Tags: arrays, explode

how to convert string multidimensional to Custom Categories with php array and explode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using a multidimensional array:

```
$string = 'type@new|color@red|company@zara|country@spain|weight@500gr|type@stoke|color@yellow|company@adidas|country@italytype@old|color@black|company@nike|country@france|type@soon|color@blue|company@reebok|country@america|insurance@yes|warranty@no';
$primaryData = explode('|', $string);
$categories = [];
foreach($primaryData as $data)
{
    $dataDetails = explode('@', $data);
    //storing each category in a separate array
    $categories[$dataDetails[0]][] = $dataDetails[1];
}
foreach ($categories as $categoryName => $categoryContents) {
    //we should only want unique categories
    $categories[$categoryName] = array_unique($categoryContents);
    //test output
    print "$categoryName category:\n";
    print_r($categories[$categoryName]);
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that the string is Dynamic.**

`$string1`="type@new|color@red|company@zara|weight@500gr";
`$string2`="type@new|color@red|company@zara";
`$string3`="type@new|color@red|company@zara|insurance@yes|warranty@no";

**for example:**

`$string`="type@new|color@red|company@zara|country@spain|weight@500gr
type@stoke|color@yellow|company@adidas|country@italy
type@old|color@black|company@nike|country@france
type@soon|color@blue|company@reebok|country@america|insurance@yes|warranty@no";